# Kubuntu 19.04 wont allow my pics as wallpapers

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background, configure

So I am trying to customise the Kubuntu desktop.  I select "add image"  navigate to my pictures and select, it displays correctly on screen, but when I reboot it reverts back to out of the box desktop.

It will allow me to select any of the other wallpapers that it has in it's collection.  Tried copying my pictures to the directory of the wallpapers but still to no avail??

Answer (score 1):

I can set the image of my choice as the wallpaper and my choice survives a reboot in Kubuntu 19.04.

The information is stored in *~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc* and here's the relevant part:

```
[Containments][58][Wallpaper][org.kde.image][General]
Image=file:///home/dkb/Desktop/Wallpaper/Next-dark.png
```

It's possible that one or more files or folders on your system do not have the correct permissions or ownership. Such a situation may arise through inadvertent use of `sudo`.

To check whether files or folders in your home folder are owned by *root*, run

```
find . '!' -user $USER -ls
```

You normally should just get back the prompt.

Here's what I see when I check files beginning with *plasma* in *~/.config*:

```
$ ls -l plasma*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb   21 Apr 18  2019 plasma-localerc
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb   69 Apr 18  2019 plasma-nm
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb   38 Aug 25 16:03 plasmanotifyrc
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 5792 Oct 19 09:23 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  128 Oct 19 06:44 plasmarc
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 2470 Oct 19 06:45 plasmashellrc
$
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I have changed OS to Linum Mint (Tina) 19.04 and everything works fine
Thanks for help